# How to retrieve recently created Approval Entity in CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, power-automate

I am trying to Cancel the approval Flow on click of a button
How to retrieve recently created Approval Entity ?
[I've created this. I have to cancel this the aprroval reuest onclick of "Recall" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILMa4.png)

Comment: Hi. Can you please add in more details on the question like adding ss or something similar?

Comment: Hey I have added screenshot link